# Using Task.Delay and a recursive call

Tags: c#, recursion, task, delay

I'm trying to figure out the best way to implement a delay into `Task` such that after the delay it calls itself again to attempt the same work.

My application is a server that generates reports from the database after the mobile devices sync their data with the server, however If another user has called the report generation method recently, I want it to pause for a period of time and then attempt to run again.

This is my current attempt

```
private static DateTime _lastRequest = Datetime.MinValue;


public async void IssueReports()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        if (DateTime.Now < _lastRequest + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3)) //checks to see when a user last completed this method
        {
            Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)); 
            IssueReports(); //calls itself again after the delay
            return;
        }
    });

    //code to generate reports goes here
    _lastRequest = DateTime.Now; //updates last request into the static variable after it has finished running

}
```

Initially if it failed the check then the task would just end. This prevented 2 users hitting the database at the same time and it causing duplicate reports to be generated. However, the problem is that if 2 users sync within that same window then the second user reports wouldn't be sent until another sync call is done.

The delay is supposed to give the server time to finish generating the reports and updating the database before the next batch is requested by calling itself.

Am I overcomplicating things? I'm worried about it potentially hammering system resources with multiple loops in the event the reports take a long time to process

Comment: You are better off using a Timer to run tasks after x minutes. `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));` will block the thread which is not a good thing in your scenario.

Comment: @i.net the method itself is called asynchronously from the clients anyway, so it wont cause a direct problem down the line - i dont think. What problems could blocking the thread cause at this point?

Comment: I don't understand at all what this code is supposed to do (even with your explanations) but want to note that your `Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2)); ` call actually does nothing because you don't wait for it to complete.

Comment: @Evk sorry, i missed the await part from that line

Comment: Then it won't compile because method is not marked with async:)

Comment: @Evk Right you are. What would be a better approach (ideally not using a timer)

Comment: Well as I said I don't understand the intention of the code, but at least start with removing `await Task.Run` completely. Then add `await` before `Task.Delay`. Maybe then it will do what you want.

Comment: @Evk Dropping Task.Run solved the problem. It's working how i expect it to now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following example run background service every 10 seconds recursively. This method is recommended only if you believe your task will complete within 10 seconds.

```
public frm_testform()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    dispatcherTimer_Tick().DoNotAwait();

}

private async Task dispatcherTimer_Tick()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs = null;
    EventHandler tickHandler = (s, e) => tcs.TrySetResult(true);

    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
    timer.Tick += tickHandler;
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
       // Run your background service and UI update here
        await tcs.Task;
    }

}
```

Comment: good chance the task could take more than 10 seconds to complete, so will increasing the interval to a period of say 5 minutes have a big impact? I'm aware that timers can become inconsistent the longer they run

Comment: Nope! it will not have a big impact. You can set time as you wish. Above code will run repeatedly for every x minutes/seconds.

Comment: Multiple timers may cause threadpool to be full and it will queue it up. If you are using less timers there is no problem with using timers in your application.